# Azure DevOps Restricted Board

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, scrum, backlog, scrumboard

Is there anyway in `Azure Devops` to restrict project members to see only their assigned `Product Backlog Items` in `Board` (and not for the others)?

I mean, by default anyone can see only his/her assigned product backlog items when entered to the `Board` section.

I don't mean filtering by the members.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Work item view/edit permissions are controlled at the Area level; if you can view the Area, you can view all work items in that Area regardless of who they are assigned to.

There is no mechanism to restrict viewing work items beyond that.

However, it's trivial for an individual to filter the board view so that they can see only their work items.